# Google custom search engine with bootstrap design

Tags: google-custom-search

I would like to ask how I can combine Google CSE with Bootstrap. I found some answers on the internet but how i guess it is not actual. Because the code which I get from google looks really differently. 
What I get from google:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '001723502654893543491:ljrinx1fco0';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

So, what I need to do is turn off the default design which is define ... uhm... I have no idea where. And set (somehow) classes of objects (textbox, button, search results ,... ) on classes from bootstrap css.